# Enterprise Architect 10 DDL generation returns incorrect SQL file when comment level set to all

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl, enterprise-architect

As mentioned in title, I want to generate DDL scripts from my data model. DDL scripts are more or less ok when in the option `Comment Level` is set up to `NONE` or `TABLE`.
The problem is that I need `Comment Level` option to be set up to `ALL`.
When it set up like this some tables are skipped and DDL script looks like this:

```
    --  Number of ............... 
)
GO
```

So it looks like `CREATE TABLE` part is missing.

Any ideas?

Thanks. 
W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that data model has been created in EA v.9 and I tried to generate DDL scripts with EA v.10

When I used EA v.9 everything was generated correctly.

Apparently they are not compatible.

Thanks. 
W.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Sparx Support. This looks like an obvious bug.